# When SET SCAN ON used after END throws error

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, ora-06550

Im trying to use SET SCAN ON after as follows..

```
SET SCAN OFF;

DECLARE
  -- declared a variable
BEGIN
  --update statement
END;

SET SCAN ON;
```

The use of SET SCAN ON; is causing the error when i try to run the script.
The error captured

```
ORA-06550: line 16, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 5):

If that is *exactly* what you are trying to run the solution is simple.  Add a `/` to finish off the anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SET SCAN OFF; 

DECLARE 
  -- declared a variable 
BEGIN 
  --update statement 
END; 
/

SET SCAN ON;
```

This is because PL/SQL syntax uses `;` to signal the end of a line of code, so we need the `/` to fire our program.

Comment: @Karthik: If it is working, you should accept the solution by clicking on the blank check mark below the solution score.